# Count the number of all words in a string

Tags: r, string, word-count

Is there a function to count the number of words in a string?
For example:

```
str1 <- "How many words are in this sentence"
```

to return a result of 7.

Comment: str_count(temp$question1," ")+1 would be easy if you know each words are separated by space. It is under library stringr.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` and `sapply` functions

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, " "), length)
```

Comment: Just an update that you can now use the somewhat new `lengths` function in base R, which finds the length of each element: `lengths(strsplot(str, " "))`

Comment: this is very good the problem is when you have something like "word,word,word" in that case it will return 1

Answer (score 82):

Use the regular expression symbol `\\W` to match non-word characters, using `+` to indicate one or more in a row, along with `gregexpr` to find all matches in a string. Words are the number of word separators plus 1.

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\W+", str1)) + 1
```

This will fail with blank strings at the beginning or end of the character vector, when a "word" doesn't satisfy `\\W`'s notion of non-word (one could work with other regular expressions, `\\S+`, `[[:alpha:]]`, etc., but there will always be edge cases with a regex approach), etc. It is likely more efficient than `strsplit` solutions, which will allocate memory for each word. Regular expressions are described in `?regex`.

**Update** As noted in the comments and in a different answer by @Andri the  approach fails with (zero) and one-word strings, and with trailing punctuation

```
str1 = c("", "x", "x y", "x y!" , "x y! z")
lengths(gregexpr("[A-z]\\W+", str1)) + 1L
# [1] 2 2 2 3 3
```

Many of the other answers also fail in these or similar (e.g., multiple spaces) cases. I think my answer's caveat about 'notion of one word' in the original answer covers problems with punctuation (solution: choose a different regular expression, e.g., `[[:space:]]+`), but the zero and one word cases are a problem; @Andri's solution fails to distinguish between zero and one words. So taking a 'positive' approach to finding words one might

```
sapply(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", str1), function(x) sum(x > 0))
```

Leading to

```
sapply(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", str1), function(x) sum(x > 0))
# [1] 0 1 2 2 3
```

Again the regular expression might be refined for different notions of 'word'.

I like the use of `gregexpr()` because it's memory efficient. An alternative using `strsplit()` (like @user813966, but with a regular expression to delimit words) and making use of the original notion of delimiting words is

```
lengths(strsplit(str1, "\\W+"))
# [1] 0 1 2 2 3
```

This needs to allocate new memory for each word that is created, and for the intermediate list-of-words. This could be relatively expensive when the data is 'big', but probably it's effective and understandable for most purposes.

Comment: `str1 <- c('s ss sss ss', "asdf asd hello this is your life!"); sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", str1), length) + 1` returns `4` and `8`. First correct, second one too many. I think it is counting the punctuation.

Comment: I think it is counting the punctuation at the end of the sentence. Pretty sure you would want to tell regex to ignore start and end matches (sorry no good with it or I would fix it myself).

Comment: `sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", "word"), length) + 1` returns 2

Comment: Thanks @fsmart -- I think the concern about punctuation is covered by the disclaimer about 'notion of non-word' in the original answer. I've updated the response.

Comment: Thanks @jaycode, the inability to count 1 (or zero) word inputs is a problem. I've updated the original answer.

Answer (score 65):

**Most simple way** would be:

```
require(stringr)
str_count("one,   two three 4,,,, 5 6", "\\S+")
```

... counting all sequences on non-space characters (`\\S+`).

But what about a little function that lets us also decide **which kind of *words*** we would like to count and which **works on whole vectors** as well?

```
require(stringr)
nwords <- function(string, pseudo=F){
  ifelse( pseudo, 
          pattern <- "\\S+", 
          pattern <- "[[:alpha:]]+" 
        )
  str_count(string, pattern)
}

nwords("one,   two three 4,,,, 5 6")
# 3

nwords("one,   two three 4,,,, 5 6", pseudo=T)
# 6
```

Answer (score 56):

I use the `str_count` function from the `stringr` library with the escape sequence `\w` that represents:

> any ‘word’ character (letter, digit or underscore in the current
> locale: in UTF-8 mode only ASCII letters and digits are considered)

Example:

```
> str_count("How many words are in this sentence", '\\w+')
[1] 7
```

---

Of all other 9 answers that I was able to test, only two (by Vincent Zoonekynd, and by petermeissner) worked for all inputs presented here so far, but they also require `stringr`.

But only this solution works with all inputs presented so far, plus inputs such as `"foo+bar+baz~spam+eggs"` or `"Combien de mots sont dans cette phrase ?"`.

Benchmark:

```
library(stringr)

questions <-
  c(
    "", "x", "x y", "x y!", "x y! z",
    "foo+bar+baz~spam+eggs",
    "one,   two three 4,,,, 5 6",
    "How many words are in this sentence",
    "How  many words    are in this   sentence",
    "Combien de mots sont dans cette phrase ?",
    "
    Day after day, day after day,
    We stuck, nor breath nor motion;
    "
  )

answers <- c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 12)

score <- function(f) sum(unlist(lapply(questions, f)) == answers)

funs <-
  c(
    function(s) sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", s), length) + 1,
    function(s) sapply(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+", s), function(x) sum(x > 0)),
    function(s) vapply(strsplit(s, "\\W+"), length, integer(1)),
    function(s) length(strsplit(gsub(' {2,}', ' ', s), ' ')[[1]]),
    function(s) length(str_match_all(s, "\\S+")[[1]]),
    function(s) str_count(s, "\\S+"),
    function(s) sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", s), function(x) sum(x > 0)) + 1,
    function(s) length(unlist(strsplit(s," "))),
    function(s) sapply(strsplit(s, " "), length),
    function(s) str_count(s, '\\w+')
  )

unlist(lapply(funs, score))
```

Output (11 is the maximum possible score):

```
6 10 10  8  9  9  7  6  6 11
```

Comment: This approach is excellent, but one issue that I still encounter with it is that it double-counts words that contain an apostrophe (e.g. "I'm" or "John's"). Is there any way to address this?

Comment: @Thredolsen if you are sure there won't be apostrophes that should be treated as word separators, you could use a character class `'[\\w\']+'` (can't test it, so https://xkcd.com/1638/ may apply), otherwise I'm not sure if regex is powerful enough to handle it in general case :)

Comment: Not sure if that's a good assumption, but if there's always only one or two letters after the apostrophe, then [`'\\w+(\'\\w{1,2})?'`](https://regexr.com/4b16c) could be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you. Both approaches work for the most part, but '[\\w\']+' appears to be better in my case, since some words contain more than 2 characters after an apostrophe (e.g.: o'clock). Related follow-up question: is there any way to also exclude cases where a colon is followed directly by a numeric character (e.g. count '10:15' as one word, rather than two)?

Comment: In this comment I'm going to be using plain regex syntax so examples are going to need some extra backslashes. To cover words like `o'clock` and `friggin'` you could do `\w+('\w*)?` (I don't know if there are words that start with apostrophe?). To additionally handle hours you could try to match them like [`\d?\d:\d\d|\w+('\w*)?`](http://regexr.com/4b2rk) or do something even more complicated depending on your needs. But this is less and less about R and more about how you define a word, so maybe you can post a separate question to cover your specific needs?

Comment: @arekolek 'allo 'allo! Agreed, this 'ere is becoming a symantics problem.

Answer (score 18):

```
str2 <- gsub(' {2,}',' ',str1)
length(strsplit(str2,' ')[[1]])
```

The `gsub(' {2,}',' ',str1)` makes sure all words are separated by one space only, by replacing all occurences of two or more spaces with one space.

The `strsplit(str,' ')` splits the sentence at every space and returns the result in a list. The `[[1]]` grabs the vector of words out of that list. The `length` counts up how many words.

```
> str1 <- "How many words are in this     sentence"
> str2 <- gsub(' {2,}',' ',str1)
> str2
[1] "How many words are in this sentence"
> strsplit(str2,' ')
[[1]]
[1] "How"      "many"     "words"    "are"      "in"       "this"     "sentence"
> strsplit(str2,' ')[[1]]
[1] "How"      "many"     "words"    "are"      "in"       "this"     "sentence"
> length(strsplit(str2,' ')[[1]])
[1] 7
```

Comment: What about tabs, new lines or nonbreakable spaces?

Comment: Way to resurrect a 5yr old answer! Use '\s' (in R, '\\s') to include any type of whitespace rather than ' '.

Comment: I've got a notification about my answer and looked at others to improve them slightly :D Don't get mad! :)
PS. I like math and coffee too!

Answer (score 14):

You can use `str_match_all`, with a regular expression that would identify your words.
The following works with initial, final and duplicated spaces.

```
library(stringr)
s <-  "
  Day after day, day after day,
  We stuck, nor breath nor motion;
"
m <- str_match_all( s, "\\S+" )  # Sequences of non-spaces
length(m[[1]])
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this function from `stringi` package

```
   require(stringi)
   > s <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    +        "nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi.",
    +        "Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.",
    +        "")
    > stri_stats_latex(s)
        CharsWord CharsCmdEnvir    CharsWhite         Words          Cmds        Envirs 
              133             0            30            24             0             0
```

Comment: @bartektartanusthat is some nice functionality!

Comment: Thank you :) Check the rest of functions from this package! I'm sure you will find something interesting :) Any comments are welcomed!

Answer (score 12):

Also from `stringi` package, the straight forward function `stri_count_words`

```
stringi::stri_count_words(str1)
#[1] 7
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use **wc** function in library **qdap**:

```
> str1 <- "How many words are in this sentence"
> wc(str1)
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
length(unlist(strsplit(str1," ")))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can remove double spaces and count the number of `" "` in the string to get the count of words. **Use stringr** and `rm_white` {**qdapRegex**}

```
str_count(rm_white(s), " ") +1
```

Answer (score 7):

```
require(stringr)
str_count(x,"\\w+")
```

will be fine with double/triple spaces between words

All other answers have issues with more than one space between the words.

Answer (score 5):

The solution 7 does not give the correct result in the case there's just one word.
You should not just count the elements in gregexpr's result (which is -1 if there where not matches) but count the elements > 0.

Ergo:

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", str1), function(x) sum(x>0) ) + 1
```

Comment: This will still have problems if `str1` starts or ends with non-word characters. If that's a concern, this version will only look for spaces between words: `sapply(gregexpr("\\b\\W+\\b", str, perl=TRUE), function(x) sum(x>0) ) + 1`

Answer (score 4):

require(stringr)

Define a very simple function

```
str_words <- function(sentence) {

  str_count(sentence, " ") + 1

}
```

Check

```
str_words(This is a sentence with six words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `nchar`

if vector of strings is called `x`

```
(nchar(x) - nchar(gsub(' ','',x))) + 1
```

Find out number of spaces then add one

Answer (score 2):

You could use stringr functions str_split() and boundary(), which will recognize the boundaries of words while ignoring punctuation and any extra spaces

```
sapply(str_split("It's 12 o'clock already", boundary("word")), length)
#[1] 4
sapply(str_split("  It's  >12  o'clock already ?! ", boundary("word")), length)
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

With **stringr** package, one can also write a simple script that could traverse a vector of strings for example through a for loop.

Let's say

> df$text

contains a vector of strings that we are interested in analysing. First, we add additional columns to the existing dataframe df as below:

```
df$strings    = as.integer(NA)
df$characters = as.integer(NA)
```

Then we run a for-loop over the vector of strings as below:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
{
   df$strings[i]    = str_count(df$text[i], '\\S+') # counts the strings
   df$characters[i] = str_count(df$text[i])         # counts the characters & spaces
}
```

The resulting columns: **strings** and **character** will contain the counts of words and characters and this will be achieved in one-go for a vector of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following function and regex useful for word counts, especially in dealing with single vs. double hyphens, where the former generally should not count as a word break, eg, well-known, hi-fi; whereas double hyphen is a punctuation delimiter that is not bounded by white-space--such as for parenthetical remarks.

```
txt <- "Don't you think e-mail is one word--and not two!" #10 words
words <- function(txt) { 
length(attributes(gregexpr("(\\w|\\w\\-\\w|\\w\\'\\w)+",txt)[[1]])$match.length) 
}

words(txt) #10 words
```

Stringi is a useful package.  But it over-counts words in this example due to hyphen.

```
stringi::stri_count_words(txt) #11 words
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, adding a `quanteda` solution. Will use the tricky example provided by [@Soren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396237/12096620) that stumps `stringi`:

```
txt <- "Don't you think e-mail is one word--and not two!" #10 words
toks <- quanteda::tokens(txt, remove_punct = TRUE, 
                         remove_symbols = TRUE,
                         remove_numbers = TRUE)
ntoken(toks) #10
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a simple solution using split and len:

```
text = 'This is a test for counting words'

# default separator: space
result = len(text.split())

print("There are " + str(result) + " words.")
```

You can get more details at
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-count-words-in-string/

Comment: This question is in `R` but this solution uses `Python`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right!