# How to return the max number of words contained in a vector of characters

Tags: string, r

I have vector of characters `c("Mark Twain", "Phil Hall", "Michael Paul O'Connor", " ",...)`

I want to know what the `max` number of words per value I can find in my vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
test <- c("Mark Twain", "Phil Hall", "Michael Paul O'Connor")

max(sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", test), length))

[1] 3
```

Also see [Count the number of words in a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920145/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
d = c("Mark Twain", "Phil Hall", "Michael Paul O'Connor")
max(sapply(strsplit(d, ' '), length))
```

Comment: +1 if you use `sapply` you don't need to use `as.numeric` due to return type

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using qdap's `wc` (word count) function:

```
test <- c("Mark Twain", "Phil Hall", "Michael Paul O'Connor")

library(qdap)
max(wc(test))

## > max(wc(test))
## [1] 3
```