# How do I count the number of words in a text (string)?

Tags: regex, r, apply, sapply

I have this string vector (for example):

```
str <- c("this is a string current trey",
    "feather rtttt",
    "tusla",
    "laq")
```

To count the number of words in this vector I used this (as given here [Count the number of words in a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920145/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-r), which is a possible duplicate but with another issue)

```
No_words <- sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", str), length) + 1
```

but it returns

```
6 2 2 2
```

String has only 1 element in last two places (i.e. `"tusla"` and `"laq"`)

so it should return

```
6 2 1 1
```

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(str, " "), length)` works for me.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik what if string has multiple spaces in between few words? for example. 
str <- c("this     is a string     current trey",
    "feather    rtttt",
    "tusla",
    "laq")

Then it does not work. It counts those extra spaces too. I hope you get it what i am trying to say.

Comment: @user3664020, the answer is in the question you have linked. `str1 <- gsub(' {2,}',' ',str);
sapply(strsplit(str1, " "), length)`. Also, `str` is a stored function in R, please try to refrain from storing your strings in there

Comment: Using `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` in `strsplit` will allow you to consider and ignore multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\S+", x), length)
## [1] 6 2 1 1
```

Or as suggested in comments you can try

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), length)
## [1] 6 2 1 1
```

Comment: Your second answer fails on "   leading and trailing    ", returning 4.

Comment: the first answer fails with empty strings "" returns 1

Answer (score 11):

Use the `stringi` package and `stri_count`:

```
require(stringi)
str <- c(
"this is a string current trey",
"nospaces",
"multiple    spaces",
"   leadingspaces",
"trailingspaces    ",
"    leading and trailing    ",
"just one space each")

> stri_count(str,regex="\\S+")
[1] 6 1 2 1 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the wc-function from the qdap package.

```
str <- c("this is a string current trey", 
         "feather rtttt", 
         "tusla", 
         "laq")

library("qdap")

wc(str)
```

That returns:

> ```
> wc(str)
>
> [1] 6 2 1 1
> ```