# Count the length of words and cut the rows which are under a threshold

Tags: r

Having data frame like this one:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("my text here", "another the here but different", "no text"))
```

How is it possible to cound for every row the number of words which has and cut the rows which have equal or less than 2 words?

Expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("my text here", "another the here but different"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option utilizing the `stringr` library could be:

```
df[!is.na(word(df$text, 3)), ]

  id                           text
1  1                   my text here
2  2 another the here but different
```

Or another option using the `stringr` library (provided by @Sotos):

```
df[str_count(df$text, fixed(" ")) >= 2, ]
```

Comment: I love the `word()` function, but I think If you are going to load `stringr`, then `str_count()` might be more straight forward, i.e. `df[str_count(df$text, ' ') >= 2,]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `gregexpr()` + `lengths()` + `subset()`:

```
dfout <- subset(df,lengths(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+",df$text))>2)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  id                           text
1  1                   my text here
2  2 another the here but different
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), text = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L
), .Label = c("another the here but different", "my text here", 
"no text"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` and `lengths` to find where you have more than 2 words.

```
df[lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$text), "\\b ")) > 2,]
#  id                           text
#1  1                   my text here
#2  2 another the here but different

df[lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$text), "\\W+")) > 2,] #Alternative
```

or using `gregexpr`:

```
df[lengths(gregexpr("\\W+", df$text)) > 1,]
  id                           text
1  1                   my text here
2  2 another the here but different
```

Have a look at [Count the number of all words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8920145/10488504).