# Subsetting List Document conditionally

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a Homework, where I'm asked to subset a list of reviews to a new list containing only reviews with 5 or less words.

Using `short_revs <- walk(mydoc, ~length(mydoc[[i]]) <= 5))` returns me the same initial List.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `short_revs <- mydoc[ lengths(mydoc) <= 5 ]` or `short_revs <- Filter(function(z) length(z) <= 5, mydoc)`. The use of `purrr::walk` operates solely in side-effect and will always return the input unchanged.

Comment: Thank you that worked immediately :)

Comment: Greetings! In the future, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

I think `walk` is not the right tool for this: it operates solely in side-effect, always returning the input unchanged. Some simple alternatives, *choose one*:

```r
short_revs <- mydoc[ lengths(mydoc) <= 5 ]
short_revs <- Filter(function(z) length(z) <= 5, mydoc]
```

Comment: But will `length` really return the number of words? That probably returns the number of characters, right? I guess it depends on exactly what is in the list.

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm inferring that it's a list of character vectors. But no, `length` will not return the number of characters (unless a sentence was first string-split with an empty pattern, ala `strsplit("hello","")`).

Comment: Oh yeah. I've been writing too much python lately. Forgive me. Plenty of options for counting words already exist here if it's one long string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920145/count-the-number-of-all-words-in-a-string

Comment: I also jump between them frequently, though I'm on a heavy R-binge recently.