# Count total of words using group by

Tags: r, string, text, data-manipulation, counting

I want to count the total number of words in text group by `id`:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3, 2), tx=c("test one. test two", "this is a test. again test", "test two", "test three times", 
                                      "test, in a future time point", "test has completed, at the final time point"))
```

How do I achieve a result like this:

```
id  word count
1   7
2   12
3   10
```

I looked at the other post [Count the number of all words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920145/count-the-number-of-all-words-in-a-string) but it doesn't show how to count words by groups.

Comment: Please reopen the question. I looked at the other question but it doesn't show how to count words by grouping

Comment: Just count the words, and then group_by/summarize like you would with any other dplyr pipleine: `df %>% mutate(words=stringi::stri_count_words(tx)) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sum(words))`. Counting words and summarizing sums are two separate problems.

Comment: you can do the following `df %>% mutate(count = stringr::str_count(tx, boundary("word"))) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(count = sum(count))`

Comment: I added the FAQ for "How to sum a variable by group?" as a reference for summarizing the data.